# Android- Tab content in the activity is lost

Tags: android, android-tabhost

```
   public class SampleTabActivity extends TabActivity implements OnClickListener{static TabHost tabHost;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Reusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab
      //this is SampleTabActivity.java file
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, TabOne.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tabOne");  
    spec.setContent(intent);  
    spec.setIndicator("Tab One");  
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams().height = 40;
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) tabHost.getChildAt(0);
    android.widget.TabWidget tw = (android.widget.TabWidget) ll.getChildAt(0);
    RelativeLayout rllf = (RelativeLayout) tw.getChildAt(0);
    TextView lf = (TextView) rllf.getChildAt(1);
    lf.setTextSize(20);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, TabTwo.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tabTwo");  
    spec.setContent(intent);  
    spec.setIndicator("Tab Two");
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).getLayoutParams().height = 40;
    RelativeLayout rlrf = (RelativeLayout) tw.getChildAt(1);
    TextView rf = (TextView) rlrf.getChildAt(1);
    rf.setTextSize(20);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, TabThree.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tabThree");  
    spec.setContent(intent);  
    spec.setIndicator("Tab Three");
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).getLayoutParams().height = 40;
    RelativeLayout rlrp = (RelativeLayout) tw.getChildAt(2);
    TextView rp = (TextView) rlrp.getChildAt(1);
    rp.setTextSize(20);
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
}}





public class TabOne extends ActivityGroup implements OnClickListener{   @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.tabone);
  TextView tv = new TextView(this);
  tv.setText("This is tab One");
  //this is TabOne.java file
  Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
  button.setOnClickListener(this);    
 }

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {   
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, TabTwo.class);         
    replaceContentView("TabTwo", intent);
    setTab(1);
}

public void replaceContentView(String id, Intent newIntent) {     
    View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(id,newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)).getDecorView(); 
    this.setContentView(view);

    }

public void setTab(int index){    
    SampleTabActivityActivity ParentActivity;    
    ParentActivity = (SampleTabActivityActivity) this.getParent();    
    ParentActivity.getTabHost().setCurrentTab(index); 
    } }




public class TabTwo extends ActivityGroup implements OnClickListener{@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  TextView tv = new TextView(this);
  tv.setText("This is tab Two");
  setContentView(tv);
 }}


public class TabThree extends ActivityGroup implements OnClickListener{@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  TextView tv = new TextView(this);
  tv.setText("This is tab Three");
  setContentView(R.layout.tabone);
 }}
```

Here, When I click continue button in TabOne...it goes to tab Two..and shows text "this is tab two"....but when I select tabOne by clicking on TabOne...the content is lost...

I cannot see Continue button again...instead I see " this is tab two "...

Please check code.
please some one help...what need to be done...where I am going wrong...????

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be in onResume() method.  onCreate() will be called if activity doesn't exists, subsequent calls will be processed by onResume() method. Refer activity life cycle in this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

Comment: which code to be written in onResume...
which file...?? which code ??

Comment: The logic you have inside onCreate() also need to be inside onResume for all activities.

Answer (score 0):

Your onClick method is hard coded, it will just go to tab two everytime you click your button.